# When one calls addEventListener without a target element what element does it default to?

Tags: javascript, dom, web, client-side, addeventlistener

```
addEventListener("load", run);

function run() {    //code }
```

The above code appears to work when I try it in a web browser. My guess would be that this is because if one uses addEventListener without a target element it defaults to the window object?

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global functions are attached to the global object, `window`.

```
addEventListener("load", run);
```

Is the same as

```
window.addEventListener("load", run);
```

Just like `alert` is the same as `window.alert`

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` and other methods/variables by default are applied to window object. Anything applied to window object becomes global. You may try to enter those lines to console and check it:

```
window.iAmGlobal = 123;

iAmGlobal;   // 123
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be refer to the window.

[image: **Here**] is a snapshot